# Unity Custom Inspector with sub-inspectors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I am working on a small ARPG in Unity 2017.2.

I have tried implementing a custom editor for the AbilityBluePrint class of my game.

Basically, the AbilityBluePrints contain all the information necessary to generate the Ability at run time. Including an array of Effect[] ScritpableObjects which get triggered when the ability is used.

I currently have everything I need implemented and working but I envisage creating abilities to be very tedious for the following reason.

Say I have an effect class DamagePlusX : Effect which as a damage modifier value. If I want this effect to have a different modifier value for two different abilities then I will have to create two instances of it in my Asset directory and manually assign each one to the Effect[] array of the corresponding ability. I am concerned that I will end up having lots and lots of instances of effects each with essentially a few different ints and floats.

I therefore thought I would use a custom inspector a bit like the one from [the Adventure Tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/adventure-game-tutorial/reactions?playlist=44381) from Unity.

The idea is to basically create the instance of the AbilityBluePrint and then use the custom inspector to be able to dynamically instantiate Effects in the Effects[] array and be able to edit the properties of each effect directly within the AbilityBluePrint inspector.

Basically I would like to get somthing a bit like that (apologies for the poor photoshop):

[image]

I tried to convert the scripts from the tutorial to fit my needs but I keep having the same error since yesterday:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
AbilityBluePrintEditor.SubEditorSetup (.EffectEditor editor) (at Assets/Scripts/Editor/AbilityBluePrintEditor.cs:90)
EditorWithSubEditors`2[TEditor,TTarget].CheckAndCreateSubEditors (.TTarget[] subEditorTargets) (at Assets/Scripts/Editor/EditorWithSubEditors.cs:33)
```

I've tried so many things I am wondering if what I am trying to do is doable with scriptable objects. In the original tutorial the equivalent of my BluePrintAbility is a Monobehaviour.

The code I have is below:

My BluePrintAbility Class:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Ability BluePrint", menuName = "Ability BluePrint")]
public class AbilityBluePrint : ScriptableObject {
    public Effect[] effects = new Effect[0];
    public string description;
}
```

My Effect class:

```
public abstract class Effect : ScriptableObject {
    }
```

My DamagePlusX effect Class:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "DamagePlusX",menuName = "Effects/DamagePlusX")]
public class DamagePlusX : Effect
{
    [SerializeField]
    int modifier;

    public void ApplyModifier(){ // some logic}
}
```

And now the Editors (apologies for the long samples, but I don't now where the error is in there, I've cut down the main classes though):

This is the base editor from the tutorial, where my error comes from:

```
// This class acts as a base class for Editors that have Editors
// nested within them.  For example, the InteractableEditor has
// an array of ConditionCollectionEditors.
// It's generic types represent the type of Editor array that are
// nested within this Editor and the target type of those Editors.
public abstract class EditorWithSubEditors<TEditor, TTarget> : Editor
    where TEditor : Editor
    where TTarget : Object

{
    protected TEditor[] subEditors;         // Array of Editors nested within this Editor.


// This should be called in OnEnable and at the start of OnInspectorGUI.
protected void CheckAndCreateSubEditors (TTarget[] subEditorTargets)
{
    // If there are the correct number of subEditors then do nothing.
    if (subEditors != null && subEditors.Length == subEditorTargets.Length)
        return;

    // Otherwise get rid of the editors.
    CleanupEditors ();

    // Create an array of the subEditor type that is the right length for the targets.
    subEditors = new TEditor[subEditorTargets.Length];

    // Populate the array and setup each Editor.
    for (int i = 0; i < subEditors.Length; i++)
    {
        subEditors[i] = CreateEditor (subEditorTargets[i]) as TEditor;
        SubEditorSetup (subEditors[i]); // ERROR comes inside this function HERE !!!!
    }
}


// This should be called in OnDisable.
protected void CleanupEditors ()
{
    // If there are no subEditors do nothing.
    if (subEditors == null)
        return;

    // Otherwise destroy all the subEditors.
    for (int i = 0; i < subEditors.Length; i++)
    {
        DestroyImmediate (subEditors[i]);
    }

    // Null the array so it's GCed.
    subEditors = null;
}


// This must be overridden to provide any setup the subEditor needs when it is first created.
protected abstract void SubEditorSetup (TEditor editor);
```

}

```
    [CustomEditor(typeof(AbilityBluePrint)), CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class AbilityBluePrintEditor : EditorWithSubEditors<EffectEditor, Effect>
{
    private AbilityBluePrint blueprint;          // Reference to the target.
    private SerializedProperty effectsProperty; //represents the array of effects.

    private Type[] effectTypes;                           // All the non-abstract types which inherit from Effect.  This is used for adding new Effects.
    private string[] effectTypeNames;                     // The names of all appropriate Effect types.
    private int selectedIndex;                              // The index of the currently selected Effect type.


    private const float dropAreaHeight = 50f;               // Height in pixels of the area for dropping scripts.
    private const float controlSpacing = 5f;                // Width in pixels between the popup type selection and drop area.
    private const string effectsPropName = "effects";   // Name of the field for the array of Effects.


    private readonly float verticalSpacing = EditorGUIUtility.standardVerticalSpacing;
    // Caching the vertical spacing between GUI elements.

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Cache the target.
        blueprint = (AbilityBluePrint)target;

        // Cache the SerializedProperty
        effectsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty(effectsPropName);

        // If new editors for Effects are required, create them.
        CheckAndCreateSubEditors(blueprint.effects);

        // Set the array of types and type names of subtypes of Reaction.
        SetEffectNamesArray();
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        // Pull all the information from the target into the serializedObject.
        serializedObject.Update();

        // If new editors for Reactions are required, create them.
        CheckAndCreateSubEditors(blueprint.effects);

        DrawDefaultInspector();

        // Display all the Effects.
        for (int i = 0; i < subEditors.Length; i++)
        {
            if (subEditors[i] != null)
            {
                subEditors[i].OnInspectorGUI();
            }            
        }

        // If there are Effects, add a space.
        if (blueprint.effects.Length > 0)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.Space();
            EditorGUILayout.Space();
        }


        //Shows the effect selection GUI
        SelectionGUI();

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add Effect"))
        {

        }

        // Push data back from the serializedObject to the target.
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        // Destroy all the subeditors.
        CleanupEditors();
    }

    // This is called immediately after each ReactionEditor is created.
    protected override void SubEditorSetup(EffectEditor editor)
    {
        // Make sure the ReactionEditors have a reference to the array that contains their targets.
        editor.effectsProperty = effectsProperty; //ERROR IS HERE !!!
    }

    private void SetEffectNamesArray()
    {
        // Store the Effect type.
        Type effectType = typeof(Effect);

        // Get all the types that are in the same Assembly (all the runtime scripts) as the Effect type.
        Type[] allTypes = effectType.Assembly.GetTypes();

        // Create an empty list to store all the types that are subtypes of Effect.
        List<Type> effectSubTypeList = new List<Type>();

        // Go through all the types in the Assembly...
        for (int i = 0; i < allTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            // ... and if they are a non-abstract subclass of Effect then add them to the list.
            if (allTypes[i].IsSubclassOf(effectType) && !allTypes[i].IsAbstract)
            {
                effectSubTypeList.Add(allTypes[i]);
            }
        }

        // Convert the list to an array and store it.
        effectTypes = effectSubTypeList.ToArray();

        // Create an empty list of strings to store the names of the Effect types.
        List<string> reactionTypeNameList = new List<string>();

        // Go through all the Effect types and add their names to the list.
        for (int i = 0; i < effectTypes.Length; i++)
        {
            reactionTypeNameList.Add(effectTypes[i].Name);
        }

        // Convert the list to an array and store it.
        effectTypeNames = reactionTypeNameList.ToArray();
    }

    private void SelectionGUI()
    {
        // Create a Rect for the full width of the inspector with enough height for the drop area.
        Rect fullWidthRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(GUIContent.none, GUIStyle.none, GUILayout.Height(dropAreaHeight + verticalSpacing));

        // Create a Rect for the left GUI controls.
        Rect leftAreaRect = fullWidthRect;

        // It should be in half a space from the top.
        leftAreaRect.y += verticalSpacing * 0.5f;

        // The width should be slightly less than half the width of the inspector.
        leftAreaRect.width *= 0.5f;
        leftAreaRect.width -= controlSpacing * 0.5f;

        // The height should be the same as the drop area.
        leftAreaRect.height = dropAreaHeight;

        // Create a Rect for the right GUI controls that is the same as the left Rect except...
        Rect rightAreaRect = leftAreaRect;

        // ... it should be on the right.
        rightAreaRect.x += rightAreaRect.width + controlSpacing;

        // Display the GUI for the type popup and button on the left.
        TypeSelectionGUI(leftAreaRect);
    }

    private void TypeSelectionGUI(Rect containingRect)
    {
        // Create Rects for the top and bottom half.
        Rect topHalf = containingRect;
        topHalf.height *= 0.5f;
        Rect bottomHalf = topHalf;
        bottomHalf.y += bottomHalf.height;

        // Display a popup in the top half showing all the reaction types.
        selectedIndex = EditorGUI.Popup(topHalf, selectedIndex, effectTypeNames);

        // Display a button in the bottom half that if clicked...
        if (GUI.Button(bottomHalf, "Add Selected Effect"))
        {
            // ... finds the type selected by the popup, creates an appropriate reaction and adds it to the array.
            Debug.Log(effectTypes[selectedIndex]);
            Type effectType = effectTypes[selectedIndex];
            Effect newEffect = EffectEditor.CreateEffect(effectType);
            Debug.Log(newEffect);
            effectsProperty.AddToObjectArray(newEffect);
        }
    }
}

public abstract class EffectEditor : Editor
{
    public bool showEffect = true;                       // Is the effect editor expanded?
    public SerializedProperty effectsProperty;    // Represents the SerializedProperty of the array the target belongs to.


    private Effect effect;                      // The target Reaction.


    private const float buttonWidth = 30f;          // Width in pixels of the button to remove this Reaction from the ReactionCollection array.

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        // Cache the target reference.
        effect = (Effect)target;

        // Call an initialisation method for inheriting classes.
        Init();
    }

    // This function should be overridden by inheriting classes that need initialisation.
    protected virtual void Init() { }


    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        Debug.Log("attempt to draw effect inspector");
        // Pull data from the target into the serializedObject.
        serializedObject.Update();

        EditorGUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;

        DrawDefaultInspector();

        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        EditorGUILayout.EndVertical();

        // Push data back from the serializedObject to the target.
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }

    public static Effect CreateEffect(Type effectType)
    {
        // Create a reaction of a given type.
        return (Effect) ScriptableObject.CreateInstance(effectType);
    }
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(DamagePlusXEditor))]
public class DamagePlusXEditor : EffectEditor {}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it will help in your exact situation, but I've had some luck with storing data in a pure C# class and then nesting an array of those inside a ScriptableObject, and the custom editors on both of those worked together.

E.g. this pure data class (which is also made up of other fairly simple pure classes):

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Buff
{
    public CharacterAttribute attribute;
    public CalculationType calculationType;
    public BuffDuration buffDuration;
    public bool effectBool;
    public int effectInt;
    public float effectFloat;
}
```

with an editor along the lines of:

```
[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof (Buff))]
public class BuffDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI (Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    ...
```

and then the SO containing an array of these "Buff" objects:

```
[CreateAssetMenu (fileName = "New Buff", menuName = "Data/Buff")]
public class BuffData : ScriptableObject
{
    public new string name;
    public string description;
    public Texture2D icon;
    public Buff [] attributeBuffs;
}
```

and finally the SO's editor (see near the bottom for PropertyField):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CustomEditor (typeof (BuffData))]
public class BuffDataEditor : Editor
{
    private const int DescriptionWidthPadding = 35;
    private const float DescriptionHeightPadding = 1.25f;
    private const string AttributesHelpText = 
        "Choose which attributes are to be affected by this buff and by how much.\n" +
        "Note: the calculation type should match the attribute's implementation.";

    private SerializedProperty nameProperty;
    private SerializedProperty descriptionProperty;
    private SerializedProperty iconProperty;
    private SerializedProperty attributeBuffsProperty;

    private void OnEnable ()
    {
        nameProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty ("name");
        descriptionProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty ("description");
        iconProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty ("icon");
        attributeBuffsProperty = serializedObject.FindProperty ("attributeBuffs");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update ();

        nameProperty.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextField ("Name", nameProperty.stringValue);
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField ("Description:");
        GUIStyle descriptionStyle = new GUIStyle (EditorStyles.textArea)
        {
            wordWrap = true,
            padding = new RectOffset (6, 6, 6, 6),
            fixedWidth = Screen.width - DescriptionWidthPadding
        };
        descriptionStyle.fixedHeight = descriptionStyle.CalcHeight (new GUIContent (descriptionProperty.stringValue), Screen.width) * DescriptionHeightPadding;
        EditorGUI.indentLevel++;
        descriptionProperty.stringValue = EditorGUILayout.TextArea (descriptionProperty.stringValue, descriptionStyle);
        EditorGUI.indentLevel--;
        EditorGUILayout.Space ();
        iconProperty.objectReferenceValue = (Texture2D) EditorGUILayout.ObjectField ("Icon", iconProperty.objectReferenceValue, typeof (Texture2D), false);
        EditorGUILayout.Space ();
        EditorGUILayout.HelpBox (AttributesHelpText, MessageType.Info);
        EditorGUILayout.PropertyField (attributeBuffsProperty, true);

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

All of which results in:

[Example Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMpK5.png)

Anyway hope that example gives you some ideas that might help with yours.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will have a think about what I would have to change to get it to work using your method. If it is doable without significant changes I will accept the answer.