# Is there any way to serialize referenced MonoBehaviours to JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json, unity-game-engine, serialization

Let's say I have an object called `ObjectA` which contains two objects: `ObjectsB` and `ObjectC`.

```
[System.Serializable]
public ClassA
{
    public ClassB classB;
    public ClassC classC;

    public ClassA()
    {
        classB = new ClassB();
        classC = new ClassC();
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public ClassB
{
    //Some fields.
}

[System.Serializable]
public ClassC
{
    //Some fields.
}
```

If I serialize `ObjectA` to JSON, `ObjectB` and `ObjectC` don't get serialized. This is what I've got after serializing `ObjectA` to JSON:
`{"_instanceB":{"instanceID":10480},"_instanceC":{"instanceID":10230}}`
I need to serialize all these objects to a file and save it locally on hard drive to be able to restore their states later. How can I do it?
Am I supposed to retrieve `ClassB` and `ClassC` from `ClassA` then serialize and save them individually? Something like this:

```
public void Save()
{
    //Get instances of ClassB and ClassC.
    ClassB classB = classA.GetClassB;
    ClassC classC = classA.GetClassC;

    //Generate different JSON for each class.
    string classA_JSON = JsonUtility.ToJson(classA);
    string classB_JSON = JsonUtility.ToJson(classB);
    string classC_JSON = JsonUtility.ToJson(classC);

    //Paths for saving locally.
    string pathForClassA = Path.Combine("C:\\", "classA.json");
    string pathForClassB = Path.Combine("C:\\", "classB.json");
    string pathForClassC = Path.Combine("C:\\", "classC.json");

    File.WriteAllText(pathForClassA, classA_JSON);
    File.WriteAllText(pathForClassB, classB_JSON);
    File.WriteAllText(pathForClassC, classC_JSON);
}
```

Looks ugly and it will generate a new JSON file for each nested class. Can I somehow serialize `ClassA` including its nested classes into one JSON file?

**P.S.** This is a Unity project and `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC` derive from `MonoBehaviour`. Since `BinaryFormatter` doesn't support `MonoBehaviour` I can't use it. The only thing that left for me is to serialize it to JSON.

Comment: Can you show us code for JsonUtility.ToJson function?

Comment: @PankajKapare `JsonUtility` documentation is available [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.html)

Comment: @Ruzihm Yes, I am aware of these limitations. `ClassB` and `ClassC` have plain float type fields which are marked with SerializeField attribute.

Comment: Since `ClassB` and `ClassC` are not `MonoBehaviour`sdid you consider to make them `structs`? I guess otherwise you might get the class references as serialized value instead of the actual values ... not sure though

Comment: @derHugo Does Unity expose struct's fields in the Inspector? I need to be able to edit them.

Comment: it should .. the only difference between a `class` and a `struct` is that `class` is a reference-type and `struct` a value-type

Comment: Damn, I forgot that `ClassB` and `ClassC` also derive from MonoBehaviour, They weren't `MonoBehaviours` from the beggin.. but  later I had to make them so could reference to them from another game object.

Comment: `so could reference to them from another game object` what do you mean? Those are components attached to GameObjects?

Comment: From the begging they were plain c# classes. but later I had to make them `MonoBehaviours` and add them as components so could reference to them from other game object.

Comment: Do they need to be components to be referenced from another game object? Can you have a component on the GameObject you would attach them to instead have a getter that returns them? Then they could be ordinary classes.  And for your inspector editing purposes, have a [custom inspector](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/editor-CustomEditors.html) for `ClassB`/`ClassC` editing.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking about now :D I'll give it a try and see if it works.

Comment: @blablaalb see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47412479/1092820) for more information

Comment: Thanks @Ruzihm and @derHugo for help. I'll try to refactor my code and make `ClassB` and `ClassC` pure c# classes and have getter properties  for them from `ClassA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I somehow serialize ClassA including its nested classes into one JSON file?

Yes you could but it would require some work:

You could have `[Serializable]` representation classes for `ClassB` and `ClassC` and use the [`ISerializationCallbackReceiver` interface](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ISerializationCallbackReceiver.html) for filling and using them in `ClassA`

Something like e.g.

```c#
public class ClassB : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float example1;
    [SerializeField] private string example2;
    // etc.

    public void SetUp(SerializableClassB values)
    {
        // set all values
        this.example1 = values.example1;
        this.example2 = values.example2;
        // etc.
    }

    public SerializableClassB GetSerializable()
    {
        var output = new SerializableClassB();

        output.example1 = this.example1;
        output.example2 = this.example2;
        // etc.

        return output;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializableClassB
{
    public float example1;
    public string example2;
    // etc
}
```

And the same for `ClassC`

```c#
public class ClassC : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float example3;
    [SerializeField] private string example4;
    // etc.

    public void SetUp(SerializableClassC values)
    {
        // set all values
        example3 = values.example3;
        example4 = values.example4;
        // etc.
    }

    public SerializableClassC GetSerializable()
    {
        var output = new SerializableClassC();

        output.example3 = example3;
        output.example4 = example4;
        // etc.

        return output;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SerializableClassC
{
    public float example3;
    public string example4;
    // etc
}
```

Then in `ClassA` you can do

```c#
public class ClassA : MonoBehaviour, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public ClassB _classB;
    public ClassC _classC;

    [SerializeField] private SerializableClassB _serializableClassB;
    [SerializeField] private SerializableClassC _serializeableClassC;


    public void OnBeforeSerialize()
    {
        // before writing to a Json get the information from the MonoBehaviours into the normal classes
        if(_classB) _serializableClassB = _classB.GetSerializable();
        if(_classC) _serializeableClassC = _classC.GetSerializable();

    }

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        // after deserializing write the infromation from the normal classes into the MonoBehaviours
        if(_classB) _classB.SetUp(_serializableClassB);
        if(_classC) _classC.SetUp(_serializeableClassC);
    }
}
```

The second huge advantage (side-effect) is that now you additionally can also controll the values of `_classB` and `_classC` directly on the `ClassA` instance. This way you can modify MonoBehaviour values in a centralized manager class.

[image]

After serializing to json using

```c#
private void Start()
{
    File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Test.txt"), JsonUtility.ToJson(this));
    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
}
```

you now get

```c#
{
    "_classB":{"instanceID":-6766},"_classC":{"instanceID":-6826},
    "_serializableClassB": {
            "example1":23.0,
            "example2":"54ththfghg"
    },
    "_serializeableClassC": {
            "example3":67.0,
            "example4":"567gffhgfhgf"
    }
}
```

Than for the example I changed it to

```c#
{
    "_classB":{"instanceID":-6766},"_classC":{"instanceID":-6826},
    "_serializableClassB": {
            "example1":47,
            "example2":"Hello"
    },
    "_serializeableClassC": {
            "example3":32.123,
            "example4":"World!"
    }
}
```

and deserialized on start from json using

```c#
private void Start()
{
    JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Test.txt")), this);
}
```

[image]